# How do I resolve MaxLimitersExceededWarning on vscode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, create-react-app, web-development-server

I am trying to create a react-app, but each time I try, it tells me to increase the limit of maxListeners and I have exceeded maxListenersExceededWarning and I am confused as to how to do that.

I tried asking chatgpt for help and I was given numerous ways to solve it. Such as updating my npm and node.js(which I already did) but all to no avail. Also tried writing codes to increase my limits of maxListeners but it didn't change anything. I am confused on what to do now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.